# Error when unzipping LiDAR data with LAStools

Tags: qgis-3, lastools, utf-8, laz

I try to unzip LiDAR data (.laz) with LAStools under QGIS 3.4 but I get following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path\to\LAStools\laszip.py", line 61, in processAlgorithm
LAStoolsUtils.runLAStools(commands, feedback)
File "path\to\LAStools\LAStoolsUtils.py", line 61, in runLAStools
feedback.pushConsoleInfo(output.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8a in position 15: invalid start byte
```

I work on LiDAR data available on government websites (i.e. the data is correct)

Answer (score 1):

Might be a very basic one, but I just ran into it.

I forgot to unzip the LASTools files in C:\ (hence the C:\LASTools folder didn't exist) before I installed it as a QGIS plugin. After unzipping everything the problem got solved.